# How to redirect route with id to not found if id doesn't exist in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a route with id `patients/:id`. I'm typing route in a browser like this `patients/10` and it shows data of a patient with id 10. The problem is when I'm typing an id that does not exist in DB it returns blank data. My expectation is, that it returns to page 404 or something like that. Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: Simply redirect to not found page. Create an if condition would work

Comment: @ShobhitTewari I have done it but it is doesn't work for nested route

Comment: Show the redirect code. Perhaps something would be unattended there.

Comment: Sure. What have you tried already though? What is the issue? We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I'm assuming that your React frontend is querying the server for each patient.

Upon making the request on the page, you could check to see if the response body is empty. If it is empty, you could redirect to a 404. If there is data, you can continue to print data on the page.

```
const isEmpty = Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
if isEmpty(response) {
    return <Redirect to="/your-404-route" />
}
// continue to print details below
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this thing by placing a condition in your API call, i.e, if your API throws an error of 404 then you simply redirect to 404-page using
`this.props.history.push('/404')`, this is an example you can use this as a reference.

Comment: Very good idea thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

For this first, you check the data that exits in the database or not.
If the data is exiting in the DB then it redirects as patients/10 URL otherwise its redirects to /error-page (error page route name).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `Navigate` or `useNavigate hook` from `react-router-dom`

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
let navigate = useNavigate();

```
    useEffect(() => {
       apiCall().then((response) => {
         setData(response.data)
      }).catch((error)=>{
          const {response} = error.response.data
            if (response.statusText === 404){
              navigate("/errorpage");
            }
        })
     },[]);
```